# why does this simple script give such a weird output?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've just started learning how to use arrays so sorry if the answer is somehow obvious. I made a simple program which i thought would just count normally. The output of this program ended up being not only backwards at first but very strange. the program is:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=1
declare -A A1
while true
do

    A1[$(($num + 1))]=$num
    num=$(( $num + 1 ))
    e=0
    for e in ${A1[@]}
    do
        echo $e
    done
    echo "e is $e"
    echo "num is $num"
    sleep 0.1
done
```

but it's output was started doing some really weird stuff after 8 as shown here:

```
1
e is 1
num is 2
2
1
e is 1
num is 3
3
2
1
e is 1
num is 4
4
3
2
1
e is 1
num is 5
5
4
3
2
1
e is 1
num is 6
6
5
4
3
2
1
e is 1
num is 7
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
e is 1
num is 8
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
e is 1
num is 9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
9
e is 9
num is 10
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
9
10
e is 10
num is 11
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
11
9
10
e is 10
num is 12
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
11
12
9
10
e is 10
num is 13
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
11
12
9
10
13
e is 13
num is 14
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
11
12
9
10
13
14
e is 14
num is 15
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
11
12
9
10
15
13
14
e is 14
num is 16
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
e is 14
num is 17
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
e is 14
num is 18
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
e is 14
num is 19
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
19
e is 19
num is 20
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
20
19
e is 19
num is 21
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
21
20
19
e is 19
num is 22
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
22
21
20
19
e is 19
num is 23
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
23
22
21
20
19
e is 19
num is 24
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
24
23
22
21
20
19
e is 19
num is 25
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
e is 19
num is 26
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
e is 19
num is 27
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
27
e is 27
num is 28
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
e is 27
num is 29
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
29
e is 29
num is 30
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
29
30
e is 30
num is 31
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
29
30
31
e is 31
num is 32
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
29
30
31
32
e is 32
num is 33
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
33
29
30
31
32
e is 32
num is 34
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
33
34
29
30
31
32
e is 32
num is 35
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
33
34
35
29
30
31
32
e is 32
num is 36
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
33
34
35
36
29
30
31
32
e is 32
num is 37
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
33
34
35
36
29
30
31
32
37
e is 37
num is 38
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
33
34
35
36
29
30
31
32
37
38
e is 38
num is 39
39
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
17
18
11
12
9
10
15
16
13
14
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
28
27
33
34
35
36
29
30
31
32
37
38
e is 38
num is 40
^C
```

can anybody explain this?

Comment: You're iterating on associative array keys. Associative arrays aren't necessarily sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared associative array, that's why output is not ordered. Change `declare -A A1` to `declare -a A1` to declare indexed array.

Like follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=1
declare -a A1
while true
do

    A1[$(($num + 1))]=$num
    num=$(( $num + 1 ))
    e=0
    for e in ${A1[@]}
    do
        echo $e
    done
    echo "e is $e"
    echo "num is $num"
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Also, your array index is not zero based. First element is A1[2]. To fix it change first line inside loop to `A1[$(($num - 1))]=$num`